# Is there a mod_top version for windows? if not is there an equivalent tool?

Tags: php, windows-server-2003, performance

Does anyone know which version of mod_top I can use for windows server 2003? I want a performance monitoring tool for PHP based web application.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could execute tasklist on the command line and parse the array of lines it outputs?

```
exec('tasklist /v /FO CSV', $strTaskList);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($strTaskList);
echo "<pre>\n";
```